# How to Save changed Data from WebPage?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im tryin to save some data from an configurationpage for users - but the i just got "null" back -.- got anyone any idea - how i could solve my problem??

Thats my Page:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <main>
            <fieldset>
            <div id="edit_trsconfiguration">
                <div id="edit_headbar">
                    <h1>Arbeitszeit - Konfiguration von:</h1>
                    <div id="edit_name">
                        <p>@(Model.Name)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="edit_headbar_positioning">
                        <div id="edit_replacement">
                            <p>Standardvertretung</p>
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                                .Name("Replacement")
                                                .DataTextField("Name")
                                                .DataValueField("SysId")
                                                .DataSource(builder => builder.Read(operationBuilder => operationBuilder.Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Action("Read", "EmployeeDropdown")))
                            )

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="edit_general">
                    <div id="edit_region">
                        <p>Region</p>
                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                            .Name("Region")
                                            .DataTextField("Name")
                                            .DataValueField("SysId")
                                            .DataSource(builder => builder.Read(operationBuilder => operationBuilder.Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Action("Read", "RegionDropdown")))
                        )
                    </div>
                    <div id="edit_language">
                        <p>Sprache</p>
                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Sprache)
                                            .Name("Sprache")
                                            .BindTo(
                                            new List<SelectListItem>() {
                                                                        new SelectListItem() {
                                                                            Text = "Deutsch",
                                                                            Value = "0"
                                                                        },
                                                                        new SelectListItem() {
                                                                            Text = "Englisch",
                                                                            Value = "1"
                                                                        }
                                            }
                                            )
                        )
                    </div>
                    <div id="edit_starttime">
                        <p>Startzeit</p>
                        @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.DefaultBeginTime)
                    </div>
                    <div id="edit_pausetime">
                        <p>Pausenzeit</p>
                        @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.DefaultBreakTime)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="edit_worktimes">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.TRSConfigTemplate)
                                        .Name("Zeiterfassungsvorlage")
                                        .BindTo(
                                        new List<SelectListItem>() {
                                                    new SelectListItem() {
                                                        Text = "Benutzerdefiniert",
                                                        Value = "1"
                                                    },
                                                    new SelectListItem() {
                                                        Text = "Vollzeit",
                                                        Value = "0"
                                                    }
                                        }
                                        )
                                        .Events(e => e.Change("onSelectTRSConfigValue"))
                    )

                    <h2>Arbeitszeiten:</h2>

                    @{
                        DateTimeDecimalConverter converter = new DateTimeDecimalConverter();
                        var mondayHours = converter.ConvertDateTimeToDecimal(Model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeMondayHours);
                        var tuesdayHours = converter.ConvertDateTimeToDecimal(Model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeTuesdayHours);
                        var wednesdayHours = converter.ConvertDateTimeToDecimal(Model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeWednesdayHours);
                        var thursdayHours = converter.ConvertDateTimeToDecimal(Model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeThursdayHours);
                        var fridayHours = converter.ConvertDateTimeToDecimal(Model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeFridayHours);
                        


                            <div id="worktimesFull" style="display:none;">
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Montag:</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">@mondayHours h</div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Dienstag</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">@tuesdayHours h</div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Mittwoch</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time"> @wednesdayHours h</div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Donnerstag</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">@thursdayHours h</div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Freitag</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">@fridayHours h</div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="worktimesCustom">
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Montag:</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">
                                    @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeMondayHours)
                                </div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Dienstag</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">
                                    @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeTuesdayHours)
                                </div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Mittwoch</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">
                                    @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeWednesdayHours)
                                </div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Donnerstag</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">
                                    @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeThursdayHours)
                                </div>
                                <p class="edit_workday_description">Freitag</p>
                                <div class="edit_workday_time">
                                    @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.TRSConfiguration.WorkTimeFridayHours)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
                @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                            .Name("zurueckButton")
                                            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "button" })
                                            .Content("Zurück")
                                            .Events(ev => ev.Click("zurueckButton")))

                @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                            .Name("neuConfigButton")
                                            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "button" })
                                            .Content("Neue Zeitkonfiguration")
                                            .Events(ev => ev.Click("neuConfigButton")))

                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </main>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

And its Controller looks like this:

```html
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditTRSConfiguration([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Guid? sysId)
        {
            Guid empSysId = sysId == null ? Guid.Empty : (Guid)sysId;
            if (empSysId == Guid.Empty)
                RedirectToAction("Index", "Administration");

            EmployeeAdministrationViewModel employeeViewModel;
            EmployeeDevice employeeDevice;
            TRSConfigurationDevice tRSConfigurationDevice;
            TRSConfigurationViewModel tRSConfigurationViewModel;
           
            using (EmployeeManagementConnector empConnector = new EmployeeManagementConnector())
            using (TimeRegistrationSystemConnector trsConnector = new TimeRegistrationSystemConnector())
            {
                employeeDevice = empConnector.LoadEmployees(empSysId, ModelLanguages.deDE).Find(x => x.EmployeeSysId == sysId);
                tRSConfigurationDevice = trsConnector.LoadTRSConfigurationDevices().Find(x => x.EmployeeSysId == sysId);
                TRSAccountDevice trsDevice = trsConnector.LoadAccountDevice(empSysId);
                AdministrationMapper mapper = new AdministrationMapper();

                //Getting the needed devices and Mapper

                tRSConfigurationViewModel = mapper.Map(tRSConfigurationDevice);

                List<EmployeeDropdownDevice> replacements = empConnector.LoadOtherEmployees(empSysId, ModelLanguages.deDE);
                EmployeeDropdownViewModel replacement = mapper.Map(replacements[0]);

                employeeViewModel = mapper.Map(tRSConfigurationViewModel, trsDevice, employeeDevice, replacement);

            }
            return PartialView(employeeViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditTRSConfiguration(EmployeeAdministrationViewModel empViewodel, Guid? sysId)
        {
                           
            return PartialView(employeeViewModel);
        }
```

But the Problem is, that i didn't become any change data back.
All data I can change on the Page is in the output just "null".

Got anyone any idea how i can get the data?

here is the input to tha page
[image]

and this is what comes out :(
[image]

would be awesome if someone could help me with my problem.

Best Regards

Comment: As far as I can see from your HTML, you haven't created any controls in the form to pass name, department, effective vaction days, default replacement, annual vacation days to the controller, from your Watch, it appears that all controls that you have created in the form that bind to a model property are being sent to your controller

Comment: Which properties are you referring to? Looking at the first 3 properties (`DefaultReplacement`, `Department` and `EffectiveReplacementDays`) you do not have any form controls for them, so nothing is sent in the post request, therefore they will be their defaults

Comment: now i changed the (HTML.BeginForm()) into: 
(Html.BeginForm("EditTRSConfiguration","Administration",Model , FormMethod.Post)
and now i become data for the user - like Department etc but no TRSConfiguration anymore -.-

Comment: You cannot add `Model` as the 3rd parameter - your model is a complex object containing properties which are complex objects - look at the `action` attribute of you `<form>` element to understand why that never work

Comment: If you do not generate form controls for each property (and every property of properties which are complex object), then their values are not sent back to the controller in the request, therefore they are their default values. But what does it matter anyway - if for some reason you need those values in the POST method, then you just get them again from the repository

Comment: so the page is for Usersettings - so the user can change some settings for his account and save them. This is why I need the new/changed Data and i don't know how to get them or save them. I thought i could get them from the POST method....

Answer (score 0):

You can model the data that you'll receive in the controller using BIND:

```
public ActionResult EditTRSConfiguration([Bind(Include = "TRSConfiguration,Sprache")] Models.EmployeeAdministrationViewModel Employee){
}
```

In there you can specify which attributes you are going to receive from the view

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question.